# $\mathbb{E}$ and Variance of the maximum of independent $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$

Tags: normal-distribution, extreme-value

I am interested in the expectation and the variance of the maximum of several independent, normal distributed variances. That is, given a set of $I$ different RVs with $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$, I want to find 
$$
  \mathbb{E}[\max~X_i], \\
  \text{Var}[\max~X_i].
$$

I have found Ross' "Computing Bounds on the Expected Maximum of Correlated Normal Variables", but the method there given requires a numerical integration. I am interested in a closed form and would prefer a closed form approximation over an exact iterative method.

Anyone can point me into the right direction?

Comment: Related: [Covariance of INID order statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41438/covariance-of-inid-order-statistics). You won't find a closed form in general, even for the expectation. I'm curious why you would find a closed form approximation preferable to an iterative method that could be more accurate: your response might help guide answers to this question.

Comment: @Brendon Independent, the article happens to have information on that as well.

Comment: @whuber I prefer a closed form so that it can be used as part of an optimization, for which I need a derivative. Thus, what I really mean is that the solution needs to be in a differentiable form.

Comment: Are you sure you need a derivative for your optimization?  There are several derivative-free methods (ones that don't substitute a finite difference approximation) available, Nelder-Mead being the most widely known for multidimensional problems.

Comment: I haven't had time to look at it in detail, but the paper _On the Maximum of Bivariate Normal Random Variables_, by Alan P. Ker, looks like it might be a useful starting point.

Comment: @jbowman The optimization is too complicated for derivative-free methods.

Comment: Related:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229073/variance-of-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables

Comment: If you need the derivative of the Emax then these could perhaps be found as the probabilities Pr(j = max_i {X_i}), so maybe what you need is rather closed form of choice probabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a closed form (well, if you accept to use special functions) for the density of $X = \max (X_1, \dots, X_n)$.

Let $F_i, f_i$ be the cdf and the density of $X_i$, for $i=1, ..., n$. The cdf of $X$ is

$$\begin{aligned} F(x) &= \mathbb P(X \le x) \\
&= \mathbb P(X_1  \le x, \dots, X_n \le x) \\
&= \mathbb P(X_1  \le x) \cdots \mathbb P( X_n \le x) \\
&= F_1(x) \cdots F_n(x).
\end{aligned}$$

Its density is then obtained by derivation:
$$f(x) = F(x)\left( {f_1 \over F_1} + \cdots + {f_n \over F_n} \right).$$

Using this, you can find expected value and variance to a good accuracy and reasonable computing time with numerical integration procedures (cf `integrate` in R).

I bet that in this case, you can permute integral and derivation with respect to the parameter, so you can obtain the derivatives in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a closed form; no numerical integration.

Comment: The difference is thin. Many 'special functions' are computed through iterative procedures, even if you don’t see it. I understand that you want to avoid doing lots of iteration so that you get something fast enough. In that case, just write the numerical integration as a sum, using, say, 10 trapezoids. This will produce a closed form approximation as requested.