# Given two independent normal random variables $X$ and $Y$, what is $P(X\leq x\mid X>Y)$?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability

As the title says, I'm looking for the distribution of $X$ given that $X>Y$.

Comment: Is this for a class? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: @gung No, it is not for a class, but my own project.

Comment: This question can be solved using a result in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77110, whose answer gives the density of the maximum of $n$ iid Normal variables.  More discussion of this circumstance also appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\mathrm{N}(0,1)$ rv's. Denote by $\phi$ and $\Phi$ the corresponding pdf and df, respectively. By definition,
$$
  P(X\leq x\mid X>Y) = \frac{P(X\leq x,X>Y)}{P(X>Y)} \ \, .
$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are iid, by symmetry we have $P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)$. But we know that $P(X>Y)+P(X<Y)=1$ (the probability of a tie is zero). Hence, $P(X>Y)=1/2$.

Now,
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X\leq x,X>Y) &= \mathrm{E}[P(X\leq x,X>Y\mid Y)] \quad \text{(total expectation)} \\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X\leq x,X>Y\mid Y=y)\,\phi(y)\,dy \\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X\leq x,X>y\mid Y=y)\,\phi(y)\,dy \quad \text{(use what you know)} \\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(y<X\leq x)\,\phi(y)\,dy \quad \text{(independence)} \\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)) I_{(-\infty,x]}(y)\,\phi(y)\,dy \\
  &= \Phi^2(x) - \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(y)\,\phi(y)\,dy \, . \\
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore,
$$
  P(X\leq x\mid X>Y) = 2\left(\Phi^2(x) - \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(y)\,\phi(y)\,dy\right) \, .
$$
Integrating by parts, we have
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(y)\,\phi(y)\,dy = \left[\Phi(y)\Phi(y)\right]_{-\infty}^x - \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(y)\,\phi(y)\,dy \, ,
$$
yielding
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(y)\,\phi(y)\,dy = \frac{\Phi^2(x)}{2} \, ,
$$
and finally
$$
  P(X\leq x\mid X>Y) = \Phi^2(x) \, .
$$

Comment: Note that $\Pr(X\le x|X\gt Y)$ = $\Pr(\max(X,Y)\le x)$ = $\Pr(X\le x\text{ and }Y\le x)$ = $\Phi(x)^2$. This agrees with your result after you perform the final integration using the substitution $z=\Phi(y)$ (no Monte-Carlo needed).

Comment: Thanks! This is much simpler. How would you prove the (intuitively clear) first equality?

Comment: You need (a) exchangeability of $X$ and $Y$ and (b) that $\Pr(X=Y)=0$. It follows immediately that $\Pr(X\gt Y)=\Pr(Y\gt X)=1/2$. A total probability law then gives $\Pr(\max(X,Y)\le x) \\= \Pr(X\le x|X\gt Y)\Pr(X\gt Y)+\Pr(Y\le x|Y\gt X)\Pr(Y\gt X)+\Pr(X\le x|X=Y)\Pr(X=Y)\\ = \Pr(X\le x|X\gt Y)(1/2+1/2)+0\\ = \Pr(X\le x|X\gt Y).\\$  All of this is essentially already in the first few lines of your answer. The remainder (about eight lines) therefore seems to be just a particularly cumbersome way to derive the distribution of the maximum of two continuous iid variables.