# Expectation of the maximum of two correlated normal variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, joint-distribution, extreme-value

I am curious what the derivation for the expectation of the maximum of two jointly normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ with correlation coefficient $\rho$.

I could start with the following but the absolute value sign under expectation doesn't look like a walk in the park:

$\mathbb{E}\left[\text{max}(X,Y)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X+Y}{2}+\frac{|X-Y|}{2}\right] = \ ...$

Comment: The distribution of $\max(X,Y)$ (for $X$ and $Y$ with equal variances and equal means) is given at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139072/.  From that you can compute the expectation (it looks like numerical methods have to be used).  The general problem (for arbitrary variances and means) looks difficult: do you need a solution in that case?

Comment: What i had in mind was the general problem..

Comment: It looks like this question has been [asked](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77110/mathbbe-and-variance-of-the-maximum-of-independent-mathcaln-mu-i-sig) before. Appologies.

Comment: I'm not sure of that: I could not find an exact duplicate.  The link in my comment was found after conducting three or four keyword searches of this site and inspecting several likely threads; it's the closest I could come.  The link you found concerns the maximum of *independent* normal variables and its answer relies fundamentally on that assumption.

Comment: About the distribution |X-Y|, the [Folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) may be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is contained in the paper [Exact Distribution of the Max/Min of Two Gaussian Random Variables](https://www.gwern.net/docs/conscientiousness/2008-nadarajah.pdf) (210 IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON VERY LARGE SCALE INTEGRATION (VLSI) SYSTEMS, VOL. 16, NO. 2, FEBRUARY 2008) by Saralees Nadarajah and Samuel Kotz cited by @Lucas in his answer at [Distribution of the maximum of two correlated normal variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139072/distribution-of-the-maximum-of-two-correlated-normal-variables)

I will give the answer here, maybe I come back to add a proof ... Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be a bivariate random vector with a binormal distribution, with means $\mu_1, \mu_2$, standard deviations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ and correlation coefficient $\rho$.  Then $X=\max(X_1, X_2)$ has probability density function $f(x) = f_1(-x)+f_2(-x)$ where
$$
   f_1(x)= \frac1{\sigma_1}\phi(\frac{x+\mu_1}{\sigma_1})\cdot 
          \Phi\left( \frac{\rho(x+\mu_1)}{\sigma_1\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}-\frac{x+\mu_2}{\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \right)              \\  
   f_2(x)= \frac1{\sigma_2}\phi(\frac{x+\mu_2}{\sigma_2})\cdot 
          \Phi\left( \frac{\rho(x+\mu_2)}{\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}-\frac{x+\mu_1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \right) 
$$
where $\phi, \Phi$ are the density and cumulative distribution function of the standard normal.

This paper also gives an exact expression for the expectation:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   \E X = \mu_1 \Phi\left( \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\theta} \right) + \mu_2 \Phi\left( \frac{\mu_2-\mu_1}{\theta} \right) + \theta \phi\left( \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\theta} \right)
$$
where $\theta = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 +\sigma_2^2 - 2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2}$.  (the paper contains more, like the variance and moment generating functions).

Comment: I have posted a proof in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/600661/20519).