# Expectation of the absolute value of the product of correlated jointly gaussians?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, transformers, absolute-value

I am reading the Performer paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14794. To understand their ReLU kernel used to approximate softmax attention, I need to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[ReLU(x^T w) \cdot ReLU(y^T w)]$ where $w \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$. I was able to reduce the problem to the more general one of computing $\mathbb{E}[|X \cdot Y|]$ where $X,Y$ are correlated jointly Gaussians. However, now I am stuck. Is there an approach of computing this expression or bound it from above reasonably without numerical simulation? Cauchy-Schwarz seems to loose for the upper bound.

Comment: Because $\text{ReLU}(z) = 0$ if $z < 0$, then you could write (using the law of total expectation) $$\mathbb{E}[ReLU(x^T w) \cdot ReLU(y^T w)] = \Pr(x^Tw \geq 0, y^Tw \geq 0) \cdot E[x^Tw \cdot y^T w \mid x^Tw \geq 0, y^Tw \geq 0]$$ Would this be easier to evaluate? I think the answer may be yes, since $w$ consists of i.i.d Gaussians, and so $x^Tw$ and $y^T w$ are both Gaussian.

Comment: I did think about this approach as well, but the conditional expectation seems really hard to evaluate. In particular, you can simplify this to $Trace(y x^T\mathbb{E}[ww^T | x^T w \geq 0, y^T w \geq 0])$. Intuitively for the dimension of $w$ large enough the expectation should yield about the identity, but how to make this exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Probably not the best solution, but a direction that may be useful.

Suppose
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\ Y
\end{bmatrix} \sim N_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\
\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 
\end{bmatrix}\right).
\end{align}

It is well known that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y = y$ is univariate normal:
\begin{align}
X | Y = y \sim N(\mu_1 + \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}(y - \mu_2), (1 - \rho^2)\sigma_1^2). \tag{1}
\end{align}

This suggests that, to bound $E[|XY|] = E[E[|X||Y||Y]] = E[|Y|E[|X||Y]]$, we can evaluate $E[|X||Y]$ first.  In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292465/how-to-find-a-closed-form-expression-for-e-maxx-y/600661#600661) (or use the property of [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution)), it is shown that if $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then
\begin{align}
E[|Z|] = \sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}} + \mu(1 - 2\Phi(-\mu\sigma^{-1})), \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is CDF of $N(0, 1)$.  $(1)$ and $(2)$ together then imply
\begin{align}
& E[|X||Y] = \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_1\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{[\mu_1 + \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}(Y - \mu_2)]^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)\sigma_1^2}} \\
+& (\mu_1 + \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}(Y - \mu_2))\left(1 - 2\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu_1 + \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}(Y - \mu_2)}{\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_1}\right)\right). \tag{3}
\end{align}

A trivial upper bound for $(3)$ is
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_1\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} + |\mu_1| + |\rho|\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}(|Y| + |\mu_2|), 
\end{align}
which gives an upper bound for $E[|XY|]$ as
\begin{align}
 & CE[|Y|] + |\rho|\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}E[Y^2] \\
=& C\left[\sigma_2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu_2^2}{2\sigma_2^2}} + \mu_2(1 - 2\Phi(-\mu_2\sigma_2^{-1}))\right] + |\rho|\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_2^2 + \mu_2^2), \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $C = \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_1\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} + |\mu_1| + |\rho|\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}|\mu_2|$.

---

##### Updates

Added R code of comparing bound $(4)$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz bound $\sqrt{(\sigma_1^2 + \mu_1^2)(\sigma_2^2 + \mu_2^2)}$. As expected, bound $(4)$ is sharper when $X$ and $Y$ are weakly correlated while Cauchy-Schwarz bound is sharper when $X$ and $Y$ are highly correlated.  Different setups of $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ also result in different winners.  Those who are interested can play with it.

```r
bounds <- function(mu1, mu2, sigma1, sigma2, rho) {
  C1 <- sqrt(1 - rho^2) * sigma1 * sqrt(2/pi) + abs(mu1) + abs(rho * mu2) * sigma1/sigma2
  C2 <- sigma2 * sqrt(2/pi) * exp(-mu2^2/(2 * sigma2^2)) + 
    mu2 * (1 - 2 * pnorm(-mu2/sigma2))
  C3 <- abs(rho) * sigma1 * (sigma2^2 + mu2^2)/sigma2
  UB1 <- C1 * C2 + C3
  UB2 <- sqrt((sigma1^2 + mu1^2) * (sigma2^2 + mu2^2))
  c(UB1, UB2)
}

para_mat <- cbind(rep(0, 10), rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10), rep(1, 10), seq(0.1, 0.9, len = 10))
colnames(para_mat) <- c("mu1", "mu2", "sigma1", "sigma2", "rho")

My_bound <- apply(para_mat, 1, function(t) bounds(t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5])[1])
CS_bound <- apply(para_mat, 1, function(t) bounds(t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5])[2])
cbind(para_mat, My_bound, CS_bound)

## Result:  
        mu1 mu2 sigma1 sigma2       rho  My_bound CS_bound
   [1,]   0   0      1      1 0.1000000 0.7334287        1
   [2,]   0   0      1      1 0.1888889 0.8140485        1
   [3,]   0   0      1      1 0.2777778 0.8893436        1
   [4,]   0   0      1      1 0.3666667 0.9589474        1
   [5,]   0   0      1      1 0.4555556 1.0222792        1
   [6,]   0   0      1      1 0.5444444 1.0784391        1
   [7,]   0   0      1      1 0.6333333 1.1260001        1
   [8,]   0   0      1      1 0.7222222 1.1625473        1
   [9,]   0   0      1      1 0.8111111 1.1834650        1
  [10,]   0   0      1      1 0.9000000 1.1774961        1
```

Comment: I did some numerical experiment, this upper bound is not uniformly tighter than the bound given by C-S inequality (i.e., for different $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \rho)$, it may or may not be sharper than C-S inequality).  So if you want to apply this upper bound, compare it with C-S bound first.

Comment: Nice idea. Could you include the code you used to run the numerical experiment?

Comment: @mhdadk  Added the updates.  Enjoy playing it :).

Comment: Did a square in (1) get lost? Should the variance not be $(1-\rho^2) \sigma_1^2$? I guess for the centered jointly Gaussians $X = w^T x$ and $Y = w^T y$ of the original formulation one would thus get $E[|X \cdot Y |] \leq \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \frac{2}{\pi} + |\rho|\sigma_1\sigma_2$ compared to what Cauchy-Schwarz gives: $E[|X \cdot Y |] \leq \sigma_1 \sigma_2$ ? So for $|\rho|=1$ the two coincide and for $\rho=0$ an improvement of $\frac{2}{\pi} $ is observed?

Comment: Actually, if $\rho = 0$, i.e. $X,Y$ independent, then according to the expectation of centred folded distributions $\mathbb{E}[|X \cdot Y|] = \mathbb{E}[|X|] \cdot \mathbb{E}[|Y|] = \frac{2}{\pi} \sigma_1 \sigma_2$, meaning your formula is tight at both endpoints $\rho=0$ and $|\rho| = 1$. Neat!

Comment: @N.Menet Yes, it should be $1 - \rho^2$, I will fix it and check the numerical results again.

Comment: @N.Menet Surprisingly, for non-zero means ($\mu_1 \neq 0, \mu_2 \neq 0$) and heteroscedastic variances, C-S bound works better under many situations.

Comment: That is indeed interesting. Thank you for your answer, it helped a great deal. I never encountered folded normal distributions before.