# Variance of maximum of Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, variance

Given random variables $X_1,X_2, \cdots, X_n$ sampled iid from $\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, define
$$Z = \max_{i \in \{1,2,\cdots, n \}} X_i$$

We have that $\mathbb{E}[Z] \le \sigma \sqrt{2 \log n}$. I was wondering if there are any upper/lower bounds on $\text{Var}(Z)$?

Comment: Just to get you started, i think you will find that $Var(Z) \le \sigma^2$ (equality is achieved at n = 1), and Var(Z) decreases as n increases. I leave it to you to provide that tighter bound as a function of n.

Comment: The sample max minus the sample min is known as the [studentized range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range) and follows the studentized range distribution if the underlying random variables are IID normal. That's at least vaguely related to what you're asking... (could give a starting point for reading). Back on your specific question, I'm sure you could write a Monte-Carlo simulation rather easily to find a practical answer.

Comment: Both answers to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105745 provide approximations to the standard deviation (and therefore to the variance), using analyses that might produce upper or lower bounds.

Comment: Related:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77110/mathbbe-and-variance-of-the-maximum-of-independent-mathcaln-mu-i-sig

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can obtain upper bound by applying Talagrand inequality : look at Chatterjee's book (Superconcentration phenomenon for instance) .

It tells you that ${\rm Var}(f)\leq C\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\|\partial_if\|_2^2}{1+\log( \|\partial_i f||_2/\|\partial_i f\|_1)}$.

For the maximum, you get $\partial_if=1_{X_i=max}$, then by integrating with respect to the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ you get 
$\|\partial_if\|_2^2=\|\partial_if\|_1=\frac{1}{n}$ by symmetry. (Here I choose all my rv iid with variance one).

This the true order of the variance : since you have some upper bound on the expectation of the maximum, this article of Eldan-Ding Zhai (On Multiple peaks  and moderate deviation of Gaussian supremum) tells you that
${\rm Var}(\max X_i)\geq C/(1+\mathbb{E}[\max X_i])^2$

It is also possible to obtain sharp concentration inequality reflecting these bound on the variance : you can look at http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/mathusers/gideon/papers/ranDv.pdf
or, for more general gaussian process, at my paper 
https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/ktanguy/files/2012/04/Article-3-brouillon.pdf

In full generality it is rather hard to find the right order of magnitude of the variance of a Gaussien supremum since the tools from concentration theory are always suboptimal for the maximum function.

Why do you need these kinds of estimates  if I may ask ?

Comment: Note that the Talagrand inequality, is an improvement of the Poincaré inequality satisfied by the standard Gaussian measure. There is more about this in Cordero-Ledoux's article "Hypercontractive measures, Talagrand's inequality and influences".

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps a lot. 

I was dealing with the problem where I was trying to bound probability of errors in estimating the length of runs of 0 in a bit stream from observations through a deletion channel. After a Gaussian approximation, the max seemed to be a natural estimator, and I found bounding its performance quite non-trivial. In my particular problem, I could find a way round it by reducing it to a Gaussian MMSE estimation problem.

Comment: @TanguyKevin what's C in the lower bound?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the expectation and variance of the range depends on how fat the tail of your distribution is. For the variance, it is $O(n^{-B})$ where $B$ depends on your distribution ($B = 2$ for uniform, $B = 1$ for Gaussian, and $B = 0$ for exponential.) See [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/a-beautiful-result-in-probability-theory). The table below shows the order of magnitude for the range.

[image]