# Limiting distribution of maximum of i.i.d. Gaussians with decreasing variance

Tags: normal-distribution, asymptotics, extreme-value

Consider a random vector $X^{(m)} = (X^{(m)}_1,\dots,X^{(m)}_m)$  where, for fixed $m$, the elements of $X^{(m)}$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 / m)$. 
Define $$Z_m =\max_{k=1,\dots,m}X^{(m)}_k.$$ What can we say about the distribution of $Z_m$ as $m$ gets large? Ideally I'd like a result such of the form $Z_m=\mathcal{O}_p(f(Z))$. Note that this problem is different than the standard problem where the variance is fixed, as is discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229073/variance-of-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275414/distribution-of-largest-sample-from-normal-distribution).

Comment: Your description of the problem is ambiguous.  Are you trying to say that the variance of $X_i$ is $\sigma^2/i$ for all $i$? In that case "iid" makes no sense.  Or are you asking about the maxima of $m$ iid vectors, all of which have variance $\sigma^2/m$?

Comment: @Aksakal It says "i.i.d."

Comment: @whuber I'm asking about the later. For a given value of $m$, the elements of the random $m$-vector are i.i.d. with a Gaussian distribution with variance $\sigma^2 /m$

Comment: Hopefully the new notation clarifies this...

Comment: Thank you; the new notation helps.  It still leaves the interpretation open, though, because $Z_m$ converges to zero in probability and if you wish to standardize it to get some nontrivial answer, you're right back in the classical case of the extreme-value distribution associated with the standard Normal.  The meaning of "fundamentally different" therefore remains obscure.

Comment: In the current formulation I can say that the distribution collapses to a point ZERO. It's not an interesting result, so you may want to reformulate the left hand size into $\sigma/\sqrt{m}Z_m$ or something along this line to make it converge to a constant distribution

Comment: @Aksakal That's not the right way to standardize; but when the standardization is done correctly (as in extreme value theory) the apparent complication introduced by dividing by $m$ disappears, as is already clear in your suggestion.

Comment: One place to find quantitative answers is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105745, which (as far as I can tell) addresses your very question.  I'm not sure, though, because of the "fundamentally different" claim.

Comment: @whuber, Aksakal is it enough that the distribution collapses to a point mass at zero? As an alternative, consider the maximum value of $X^{(m)} = X^{(m)}_1,\dots,X^{(m)}_{2^m}$ i.i.d. Gaussian's with variance $m^{-1}$. It's not obvious to me that this should converge to a finite number (or zero)

Comment: Re: the accuracy of my "fundamentally different" claim, I think answer to my above comment might help me figure that out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [lesson of extreme value theory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105745) is that when you rescale the maximum of $m$ iid standard Normal variables by an amount proportional to $\sqrt{2\log m}$ and shift that to a location near $\sqrt{2\log m},$ it converges to the standard Gumbel distribution as $m$ increases.

If first you rescale your $m$ iid Normal variables by $\sqrt{m},$ they become standard Normal, and the preceding applies.

> Consequently, for suitable constants $\alpha$ and $\beta,$
>   $$Z_m \beta \sqrt{2m\log m} - \alpha \sqrt{2\log m}$$
>   converges to a Gumbel distribution.

In particular, this means we may approximate $Z_m$ closely (in distribution) by

$$Z_m \approx \frac{Y }{\beta \sqrt{2m\log m}} + \frac{\alpha}{\beta\sqrt{m}}$$

for a Gumbel variate $Y.$  Since the denominators diverge, the (unnormalized) limiting distribution of $Z_m$ is $0$ (in probability).  Notice that it does so by being squeezed narrowly around a positive value $\alpha / (\beta\sqrt{m})$ while this central value creeps slowly down towards zero.  Here's a histogram with $m=10000$ based on $4000$ such samples:

[image: Figure]

The red curve plots the limiting Gumbel density, $f(y) = \exp(-e^{-y} - y).$

Comment: The link "lesson ..." seems wrong. I guess it should define $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Yves Oops, you're right: the last digit "5" of the thread id was cut off during the pasting.  I'll fix that right away.